# WinRT loading ResourceDictionary from string

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, resourcedictionary

I need to change `ResourceDictionary` values based a config that comes from the server.

The way I've gone about this is to have a resource file that I open and read the content into a string, do some replacements on it, then write the string back to a file in the temp folder.

What I need to do now is to load the file into the `ResourceDictionary.Source` which takes a URI.

If I take `StorageFile.Path` and use that for the URI, it doesn't work.

```
var resource = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri( storageFile.Path )
};
```

This give me the error `Value does not fall within the expected range.`.

I have tried

```
new Uri( "ms-appdata:///temp/" + storageFile.Name )
```

and that give me the error `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`.

I have tried using the local folder instead, which gives me the same errors.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try loading it using [`XamlReader.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.aspx).

Comment: Once again, you're awesome. Thanks!